# why .stl-model in blender differ from .stl-model in makerware?

Tags: edges

I made Blitzcrank even though it's not blitzcrank.

[image]

[Fig-1]

Fig-1 Doesn't have edge on face.

.stl file is made in blender and exported.

when i import .stl file into makerware, i see Fig-2.

[image]

[Fig-2]

edge was suddenly made in makerware!

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like the result of triangulation to me. If a quad is not planar it will show up in flat shading, after it is triangulated. You will notice the same effect in Blender when converting quads to triangles. The mesh also contains flipped normals and doesn't look manifold. You can use the bundled 3D Printing Toolbox (Addon) to find issues.

Answer (score 1):

That is the result of non-planar faces.  STL files only support tris (partly for this exact reason).  So when you export a mesh to .stl, Blender will automatically triangulate all faces.  So if a face's vertices are only slightly non-coplanar, in Blender it won't look strange, but once the model is triangulated you will definitely be able to see the extra edge placed across the face.

The solution is to either model in tris, or to manually make the non-planar faces planar.  The latter solution is probably your best bet now, though it is kind of ugly.

As a side note I noticed that some of your normals are inverted (the darker faces), this might cause problems if you are planning on 3D printing your model.  To fix this simply select the faces and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > *invert normals*.